# Integrating Selenium Test Suite (Eclipse) with TFS

Tags: java, eclipse, visual-studio-2012, selenium, tfs

I've been asked a question by one of our developers here. They are asking whether it is possible for a selenium test suite to be tied in with a TFS build in visual studio to the test server? So that way, as soon as a build is done it can kick off a run of the regression test suite, directly after that.

Bear in mind that my scripts have been written in Eclipse, NOT Visual Studio, so I'm not sure if this will cause restrictions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call UI scripts as you describe and I would additionaly recommend that you use Release Management to do this rather than build. It makes much more sense to use a deployment engine rather than a compilation engine to maintain this. One does not usually have an instance of ones application running on the build server.

http://nakedalm.com/execute-tests-release-management-visual-studio-2013/

You need to get a few things lined up, but it worked pretty good..

Comment: great, thanks a lot. So the fact I am writing my selenium scripts in Selenium shouldn't cause any difficulties?

Comment: Should not. There are some hoops to create the association with Test Cases, but there are lots of solutions.

Comment: That's great thank you. I've had a glance over the link you sent me, so once I've got some time assigned I'll use it as my guide. I take it, this will act as a good starting point?